Multiple themes depends on a route
I have 5 pages with equal structure and 5 themes (1 page = 1 theme). Themes files has equal structure too and just contains sass variables with color palette and background image. So I want to switch theme on every page
App root file:
<template>
   <div class="main"></div>
</template>

main.scss:
.main {
    background-color: $themeColor;
}

Theme file 1 structure:
$themeColor: black

Theme file 2 structure:
$themeColor: white

So I want on route 1 to have a themeColor variable to be 'black' and on route 2 - 'white'
I tried dynamic import inside route watcher, but it doesn't work

I would suggest using css :root variables instead of sass variables. You can create :root variables in each page's head method. (suppose you're using nuxt.js)
page files
head() {
 return {
   style: [
        {
          cssText: `
            :root {
              --background-color: 'black'; // black or white based on page url
            }
          `,
          type: 'text/css'
        }
      ]
   }
}

main.scss
.main {
backgroundColor: var(--background-color);
}


In page files, --background-color can be set based on page's variables. Here is the reference.
